# SurfaceListBoxItem Trigger IsSelected

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Good day!

I have `SurfaceListBox` and its Item template designed using `XAML`. I have added a trigger of `IsSelected = true` which works fine however I want to deselect it in case the same item is selected again. I am able to do it if another item is selected but not able to deselect the same item.

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="SelectTxt" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        <Setter TargetName="DeselectTxt" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        <Setter TargetName="SelectionBorder" Property="Background" Value="#3ab175" />
        <Setter TargetName="CheckMark" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        <Setter TargetName="CheckBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="White" />
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

I want to revert all the setter properties on deselection.

Comment: Can you explain more on your expected result? I am not getting, why you want to de-select if it's already selected.

Comment: Its a simple checkbox kind of mechanism. I want to select an item and de-select it as user can select multiple items and remove some

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `CheckBox` to your `ItemTemplate` to achieve Selection & DeSelection. In this, `CheckBox`'s `Checked` property is binded to `IsSelected` of your `ListViewItem`. So, your existing `Triggers` would work as it is.

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <CheckBox Content="{Binding}" 
                  Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"
                  IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

If you do not want to see the `CheckBox`, you can use `ToggleButton` to get the same functionality. Like,

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ToggleButton Content="{Binding}" 
                      Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"
                      IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}">
            <ToggleButton.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                    <Border BorderThickness="0">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ToggleButton.Template>
        </ToggleButton>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Note: Use appropriate property name for the `CheckBox` & `ToggleButton` content binding.

Comment: I was avoiding the change to add CheckBox however I would now use it. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @JibяaᴎKhaᴎ if so, you can also use `ToggleButton` for the same. Please check my updated answer for the same.